# Why output previous props in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I use like `const { number } = this.props` in React, I get some confucious things, please see console, why two numbers is different when first output.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      number: 0
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        number: 9
      })
    }, 1000)
  }
  render() {
    return <Child number={this.state.number} />
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { number } = this.props
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.props.number, number) // here, why two numbers is different when first output.
    }, 2000)
    return <h2>please see console, why two numbers in fisrt line in console output is different</h2>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
, mountNode);
```

```html
<div id="container" style="padding: 24px"></div>
<script>
  var mountNode = document.getElementById('container');
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Child` component's render method will be called twice,

1. During initial mount of `App` with state number as 0
2. Then one second after App's `componentDidMount` executes, state is changed to number:9.

So render is called twice in one second gap. In first call number is 0 and second number is 9. Problem is you are timing out console.log for 2 seconds, by that time `this.props.number` would be 9.

But the first execution of console log saw that number is 0 and it is bound to its closure. 
so it prints 9 and 0

the second one prints 9 and 9